# How to mask out a view when filling an area?

Tags: iphone, uiview, masking

could anyone tell me how to place a translucent black mask over the whole screen, but with the area of a particular UIView being excluded? I want to use this mask over a UITextField, which calls resignFirstResponder when the outside part of the textfield is tapped.

The subview tree would be like:

UIWindow
|-UIView
| |-UITextField
|
|-Mask

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried drawing an object created with the frame of the object you want to mask?

Comment: sorry, my words must have been confusing. I wanted the mask to cover the whole screen, with just the area of a particular view being excluded.

Comment: Hmmm... I swear there's a Core Graphics method for that kind of stuff. I'll look into it. I don't use the low level graphics stuff much so I have to dig...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the:

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

And send the UITextField to the front after you add the black mask view.

**UPDATE**

Ok this are the steps to do it (you can see the apple example for UIGestureRecognizers for more)

1. create a mask view (programmatically or with IB) and call it "maskView".
2. create a gestureRecognizer and add it to the maskView.

   ```
           UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
           recognizer.delegate = self;
           UIImageView *maskView =  [[UIImageView alloc] init];
           [maskView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
   ```
3. you will need to set your view controller as the delegate for "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate"

   ```
   @interface YourViewController : UIViewController   <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
   ```
4. add the maskView to your ViewController when you want to mask the screen. and then move the text field above the mask.

   [self.view addSubView:maskView];
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:textField];
5. set this 2 functions:
   in the first one you can set the action if the user touches the mask

   ```
   - (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
   //resign the first responder when the user taps the mask
    //you can remove the mask here if you want to
   ```

   }
   in the second one you tell the app not to receive touches from the textField

   ```
   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

   // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
   if ((touch.view == textField)) {//checks if the touch is on the textField
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
   ```

   }

Hope it make some sense

shani

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sorry, I hadn't made my points right again. I've added a subview tree diagram to my post. I want the mask to cover the whole window, so the mask must be the subview of the window, not of the parent view of the textfield.

Comment: Hey. Why is it important for you to mask the window and not the view?

Comment: because I want the responder to be resigned when any point of the window is tapped.

Comment: So why cant you add a gesture recognizer to the mask and exclude the text field?

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer. hope it will help.